# PHP arrays - a 'set where key=?' type function?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach, logic

Is there a built in php function that allows me to set a value of an array based on a matching key? Maybe i've been writing too much SQL lately, but i wish I could perform the following logic without writing out nested foreach array like the following:

```
foreach($array1 AS $k1 => $a1) {
    foreach($array2 AS $a2) {
         if($a1['id'] == $a2['id']) {
              $array[$k1]['new_key'] = $a2['value'];
         }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way to do this? In SQL logic, it would be "SET array1.new_key = x WHERE array1.id = array2.id". Again, i've been writing too much SQL lately :S

Comment: For what it's worth, I don't think that would update the original array. Wouldn't you have to change the first loop to say `&$a1`?

Comment: @Jonathan Coe, what you're trying to do is actually not that trivial, so I doubt there's any built-in way to do it.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc You are correct, sorry I miswrote the code... in my actual code, I am updating the original array, not the alias, my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I need to do this, I use a function to first map the values of one array by id:

```
function convertArrayToMap(&$list, $attribute='id') {
    $result = array();
    foreach ($list as &$item) {
        if (is_array($item) && array_key_exists($attribute, $item)) {
            $result[$item[$attribute]] = &$item;
        }
    }
    return $result;
}

$map = convertArrayToMap($array1);
```

Then iterate through the other array and assign the values:

```
foreach ($array2 AS $a2) {
     $id = $a2['id']; 
     $map[$id]['new_key'] = $a2['value'];
}
```

This are less loops overall even for one pass, and it's convenient for further operations in the future.

Comment: Ahh... I like that. Certainly not less code, but more a more efficient process is definitely worth the extra.

Comment: Yeah, in addition, if you put the above function into a library (as I have) then it *is* less code in each usage of it.

Comment: Yea, it is a class method for me, just trying to simplify it. Nested foreach loops arent usually the best way to accomplish this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1):

This one is fine and correct

```
foreach(&$array1 AS &$a1) {
    foreach($array2 AS $a2) {
         if($a1['id'] == $a2['id']) {
              $a1['new_key'] = $a2['value'];
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `foreach($array1 AS &$a1) {` and `foreach($array2 AS $a2) {`?

Comment: @Rocket: I think it should be `&$array1 as &$a1`, but to be honest, I'm not sure, now

Comment: Pretty sure you don't need `&$array1`.

Comment: It works either way ;) 

I might be noobing all over the floor here, but why use & in the first place? It works without it, is it a best practices thing?

Comment: @JonathanCoe: I doubt it works. & before $array ensures that when you change $a1, $array1 will change, too

Comment: Guys, read the question, the OP is not asking to have his code fixed, he's asking for a different way to do it.

Comment: @genesisφ Sorry, you are correct.... I'm actually updating $array1 not $a1, thats why it works... i'll change the question to match.